# Windows 7 bootmgr is missing plus partitions are wonky

Tags: windows-7, boot-partition

I rebooted a machine for the first time in a few months to try and sort out why my internal large media drive is disappeared/bring it back up. I poked around, didn't change any hardware, and on bootup, bootmgr is missing.

It took me a few days to find the Win7 CD, in the meantime I looked around with AOMEI, and found my C: and D: drives lettered opposite what they should be (which I eventually fixed by swapping their SATA ports).

I tried repairing MBR, no luck. Once I found the Win7 CD, repair failed/ would say it's the wrong version (i think it's not).

There is only one Windows install across all drives, and I noticed that the reserved system partition (100MB) kept getting a drive letter. I cleared that, rebooted, still bootmgr missing.

Running a Linux boot disk, I am able to access the files on what should be my C: drive, but I noticed in AOMEI that the actual windows install partition has no mount point, is listed as red, while everything else is green.

I imagine I've gotta poke around in BCD and friends land, but I've never done it before, so am hoping for a little guidance on that, and if I need to do anything to the C: partition to make it work.
Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the SMART info of the disk and add it to your post. (Your post could also do with some dividing of the text into paragraphs.)

Comment: SMART show clear across the board.  


I swear it had paragraphs in preview, but I let edit autofix it. C:/Dir shows the drive contents as well, so everything's definitely there, just some part of the boot bits is sideways.  Double spacing isn't giving me a newline, not sure what's going on.

Comment: Is your Windows 7 boot CD and corrupted disk installation, both at SP1?

Comment: Not sure on disc, but OS is as current as it could be.

Comment: You could try reinstalling Windows to the same partition, in the hope that it will detect the existing installation and just repair it. Save first any irreplaceable data.

Comment: I'd rather try and get this running again through cmd line poking. I just dont want to go into it blind. If I can't get it running this week, then next weekend I'll get a drive, clone the data and go Win10.  
I'm 90% sure it's just something needs to be edited on main C partition, or boot bits need rebuilding, manually.

Comment: In the time you have spent researching this challenge, you could have spent 1/100th the amount of time to extract all of your personal data to an external drive, reformat the drive and "Unallocate" it, and re-install a fresh OS, and configure it, and make a backup image of the fresh install, with all the drivers and C++ and .NET and etc... and moved on... ••• Just sayin', mate! Is it the building burning that is important, or the people and information dwelling within that burning building... that the "Firemen" want to hold a committee meeting over. •7•  Forgive my being crass. All the best